# jQuery, multiple hover, optimize code

Tags: jquery, query-optimization, hover

I created a code that changes the position of the background when mouse over, I'm pleased with how it works, but I have about 50 possible positions and this code looks very cumbersome. Rows with "mouseover" and "mouseout" virtually identical, only the numbers changing. Is it possible to simplify this code, that would not write the same thing over and over again?

```
$('.b-test a').addClass('over-1')

$('.b-test a.over-1').live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "0 -120px");
});
$('.b-test a.over-1').live("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).addClass("over-2").removeClass('over-1');
}); 
$('.b-test a.over-2 ').live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "0 -240px");
});
$('.b-test a.over-2 ').live("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).addClass("over-3").removeClass('over-2');
});
$('.b-test a.over-3 ').live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "0 -360px");
});
$('.b-test a.over-3 ').live("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('over-3').addClass("over-4");
});
$('.b-test a.over-4 ').live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "0 0");
});
$('.b-test a.over-4 ').live("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('over-4').addClass("over-1");
});
```

And one more question. Can I set random background position when mouse hover, but it should be multiple 120?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: you should really ask this question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could declare an object which holds the relation between class and y position?
A bit like this:

```
var positions={
    'over-1': -120,
    'over-2': -240,
    'over-3': -360,
    'over-4': 0
}
```

and then rewite your code like this:

```
$('.b-test a').addClass('over-1')

$('.b-test a').live("mouseover", function()
{
    var pos=positions[$(this).attr('class')];
    $(this).css("background-position", "0 "+pos+"px");
});
```

of course, this assumes that the elements in question only have one class.

**Edit**

If your elements have or are likely to have more than one class, you could iterate over the objects members to check which one it is, like this:

```
$('.b-test a').addClass('over-1')

$('.b-test a').live("mouseover", function()
{
    var firstclass='',nextclass=false, classchanged=false;
    for(className in positions)
    {
        if(firstclass=='')
        {
            firstclass=className;
        }
        if($(this).hasClass(className))
        {
            var pos=positions[className];
            $(this).css("background-position", "0 "+pos+"px");
            $(this).removeClass(className);
            nextclass=true;
        }
        else if(nextclass)
        {
            $(this).addClass(className);
            nextclass=false;
            classchanged=true;
        }
    }
    if(!classchanged)
    {
        $(this).addClass(firstclass);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Gareth this works only once, ie after the first hover nothing else happens. Here's an example test.xhtml4u.ru/over/index.html the first picture with my code, the second with yours. Maybe I misunderstood something, I'm a designer, not a programmer:) Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Garet unfortunately the same result (I have updated the test page with your code).
I think so, that the problem is that you only use the "mouseover" but after the "mouseover"we need to use "mouseout" what would the process went on ... I hope you understood what I wanted to say, thank you.

Comment: @Kuzzy I don't think you need to use both mouseover and mouseout. I've made a couple of small changes where I'd made (more) mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to make an array with a slot for each Y-Position (putting a null in position 0 since you have no `a.over-0` object), and loop through them thusly. (Not fully tested, but the idea is there)

```
$('.b-test a').addClass('over-1');

var items = new Array(null, '-120px', '-240px', '-360px', '0');

for (var x=1; x<items.length; x++){
    var nextItem = (x==items.length-1) ? 1 : x+1;
    $('.b-test a.over-' + x).live("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).css("background-position", '0 ' + items[x]);
    });
    $('.b-test a.over-' + x).live("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).addClass('over-' + nextItem).removeClass('over-' + x);
    }); 
}
```

If you want to use random Y-Coordinates, try this...

```
$('.b-test a').addClass('over-1');

var items = new Array('-120px', '-240px', '-360px', '0');

for (var x=1; x<items.length; x++){

    //Find a random spot in the items array and use that as Y-coord
    var currentY = items[Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * item.length + 1 ) -1];

    var nextItem = (x==items.length-1) ? 1 : x+1;
    $('.b-test a.over-' + x).live("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).css("background-position", '0 ' + currentY ); //<----- change
    });
    $('.b-test a.over-' + x).live("mouseout", function(){
        $(this).addClass('over-' + nextItem).removeClass('over-' + x);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, both examples do not work. Nothing happens when mouse hover :( You can see it here jivebelarus.net (the red figure in the header with a white cross)